# C# run throw External component has thrown an exception

Tags: c#

When I'm trying run with VS found an error as below.

**External component has thrown an exception.**

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception``
   at System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper.InitializeAndCreateSession(OleDbConnectionString constr, SessionWrapper& sessionWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectio``nClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at MappingChipset.MappingChipset.GetExcelSheetNames(String connectionString)
   at MappingChipset.MappingChipset.Parse(String fileName)
   at MappingChipset.MappingChipset.mappingBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Who can help me?

Comment: This error often related to VS build configuration & platform usage of MS OLEDB driver (x86/IA-32 or x64). Can you provide details what kind of scenario you trying to run (seems that WinForms tried to open connection to an Excel or Access file using `OleDbConnection`)?

Comment: It's a Win7 SP1 x64, office version is 2016, I don't know what information is useful for you debug,

Comment: Check these conditions first: have you setting build options & using ACE OLEDB driver (Office System Driver) for x64? Is your Office 2016 uses 64-bit version? Also try putting `OleDbConnection` code which caused this issue to give more light.

Comment: Use ACE oledb 12.0 wtih VS2015, but I found is fail on EXCEL 2016 units

Comment: Office 2016 may require `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` driver instead of `12.0`. Hence, the provider connection string should be containing `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0`.

Comment: but i try this 16.0, it will appear Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data) ,  and I add reference 16.0 library, I don't know why

Comment: I found can solve by use "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'"   but I don't know what different with "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'"

Comment: The first connection string uses JET OLEDB provider (works for XLS), whereas the second one uses ACE OLEDB provider (works for XLSX). `IMEX=1` parameter must be used if column data contains numbers/dates (will read as strings) and `HDR=NO` being set (no header column).

Comment: In excel 2010 or 2013, you're right,   JET OLEDB work for xls, ACE OLEDB works for XLSX, but XLSX will get error message no matter what ACE or JET OLEDB on Excel 2016 system , Do you know why?  thanks!

Comment: In excel 2010 or 2013, you're right, JET OLEDB work for xls, ACE OLEDB works for XLSX, but XLSX will get error message no matter what ACE or JET OLEDB on Excel 2016 system , Do you know why? thanks! –